# Library not loaded error and Abort trap: 6 when using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

After updating my mac to high sierra, I can't use `ffmpeg`

```
$ ffmpeg
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libidn2.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libgnutls.30.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: reinstall `ffmpeg`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem after a security update. I found [this Github issue](https://github.com/pymedusa/Medusa/issues/3400) with the same error message for `ffprobe`, a sister program. The solution was to uninstall and install again.

On `macOS`, I did:

```
brew uninstall ffmpeg
brew cleanup
brew install ffmpeg
```

Depending on your installation, you may need to run `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ffmpeg` (if you have dependencies such as `opencv` that require `ffmpeg`) or `brew uninstall --force ffmpeg` (if you have multiple versions).

And now FFMPEG works:

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
...
```